# How do I pause a setInterval on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slideshow displaying using setInterval. I would like it to pause, not clear, when the user hovers over the slideshow. Below is what I have so far. Thanks!

```
$(function changeSlide() {
  var i = 0;
  var autoplay = setInterval(function(){ 
    if(i<5)
    {
      $(".Slideshow").slick('slickGoTo',i);
      i++;
    }
    else
    {
      $(".Slideshow").slick('slickGoTo',0);
      clearInterval(autoplay);
    }
    $(".Slideshow").hover(function(){
        // pause interval while hovering
      });

  }, 4000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pause, but what you can do is clear the interval and then restart the interval on mouseout:

```
$(".Slideshow").hover(function(){
    clearInterval(autoplay);
}, function () {
    //mouseout function
    changeSlide();//start everything again
});
```

Comment: That's what I tried right after I posted my question. Thanks! Just wasn't sure if there was some type of way to pause.